# c++ library for endian-aware reading of raw file stream metadata?

Tags: c++, image, metadata, filestream, endianness

I've got raw data streams from image files, like:

```
vector<char> rawData(fileSize);
ifstream inFile("image.jpg");
inFile.read(&rawData[0]);
```

I want to parse the headers of different image formats for height and width. Is there a portable library that can can read ints, longs, shorts, etc. from the buffer/stream, converting for endianess as specified?

I'd like to be able to do something like: `short x = rawData.readLeShort(offset);` or `long y = rawData.readBeLong(offset)`

An even better option would be a lightweight & portable image metadata library (without the extra weight of an image manipulation library) that can work on raw image data. I've found that Exif libraries out there don't support `png` and `gif`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that hard to do yourself.  Here's how you can read a little endian 32 bit number:

```
unsigned char buffer[4];
inFile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

unsigned int number = buffer[0] +
                      (buffer[1] << 8) +
                      (buffer[2] << 16) +
                      (buffer[3] << 24);
```

and to read a big endian 32 bit number:

```
unsigned char buffer[4];
inFile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

unsigned int number = buffer[3] +
                      (buffer[2] << 8) +
                      (buffer[1] << 16) +
                      (buffer[0] << 24);
```

Comment: I generalized that to this:

`template<class T> T Magic::getLE(const char* data) const { T value = 0; int bytes = sizeof(T); for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) { value += data[i] << CHAR_BIT * i; } return value; }`

Should work, right?

Comment: Actually, code above has a bug. Instead of shifting `chars` over one at a time, it shifts `T` one over at a time. This fixes that: `template<class T> T Magic::getLE(const char* data) const { T value = 0; int bytes = sizeof(T); unsigned char c; for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) { c = data[i]; value += c << CHAR_BIT * i; } return value; }`